# Interpolate every value up to 5 years - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, interpolation

I have below table with Swedish swaprates.
I am making a forward-looking PnL-report and therefore want to know what my basis rate would be on maturity rate for a bond so I can evaluate whether we should reinvest immediately on maturity date or not.

Lets say bond `X` matures at 2017-03-01, I would then like to know the interpolated value for that day based on 3 months and 6 months. 
I have like 130 different bonds with different maturity dates up to 5 years.
Is there a smooth way to, based on below values, interpolate every single day up to 5 years?

```
name    |   ccy |   price   |   datedays    |   timeband    |   Rate_Date
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.562  |   1           |   OVERNIGHT   |   2016-10-07
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.559  |   7           |   1 WEEK      |   2016-10-13
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.631  |   32          |   1 MONTH     |   2016-11-07
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.577  |   61          |   2 MONTHS    |   2016-12-06
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.741  |   95          |   3 MONTHS    |   2017-01-09
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.349  |   182         |   6 MONTHS    |   2017-04-06
SWAP    |   SEK |   -0.499  |   369         |   1 YEAR      |   2017-10-10
SWAP    |   SEK |   -0.403  |   734         |   2 YEARS     |   2018-10-10
SWAP    |   SEK |   -0.285  |   1099        |   3 YEARS     |   2019-10-10
SWAP    |   SEK |   -0.151  |   1467        |   4 YEARS     |   2020-10-12
SWAP    |   SEK |    0.003  |   1831        |   5 YEARS     |   2021-10-11
```

See `Value1` and `Value2` below, which are interpolated.
`Value1` is calculated like this:

```
Inteprolating factor = Price(Stibor2M) - Price(Stibor1m) / ( datedays(2m)-datedays(1m) ) 
-->
(-0,741 - -0,631)/(61-32) = 0,0018621
```

So, between Stibor 1M and Stibor 2M, we add this amount every day.

To see how many days it is between first measure and desired measure:

```
Datedays(Value1) - Datedays(Stibor 1M) = 50-32 = 18
```

Interpolated value for 2016-11-25 will then be:

```
Price(Stibor1M) + 18 * interpolating factor = -0,631 + 18*0,0018621 = -0,597483
```

.

```
name    |   ccy |   price   |   datedays    |   timeband    |   Rate_Date
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.562  |   1           |   OVERNIGHT   |   2016-10-07
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.559  |   7           |   1 WEEK      |   2016-10-13
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.631  |   32          |   1 MONTH     |   2016-11-07
Value1  |   SEK |   -0.597  |   50          |   -           |   2016-11-25
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.577  |   61          |   2 MONTHS    |   2016-12-06
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.741  |   95          |   3 MONTHS    |   2017-01-09
Value2  |   SEK |   -0.607  |   146         |   -           |   2017-03-01
STIBOR  |   SEK |   -0.349  |   182         |   6 MONTHS    |   2017-04-06
```

Comment: If you add a table with expected results and explain the logic and formulas for the calculations, there is a chance somebody would be able to answer the question. Right now it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry, added one example now.

Comment: One common way to get a result set with one row per date is to use a [`Calendar`](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) table - a helper table with a `date` column and values for all days of needed years. You populate this table once in advance and use it in such queries.